# Filtering out Partial IP Address in Wireshark

Tags: filter, ip, wireshark

I'm trying to filter through a Wireshark capture.  I'm trying to find exactly where something breaks, however the specific type of traffic is working for many devices and broken for many others.  The ones that are working all have IP addresses that end in .60 or .61, while none of the others do.  I've attempted to filter these out one by one, but the filter is now 9 lines long, and I'm still pulling up more IP addresses.  Anyone have any Wireshark filtering voodoo that might be able to assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable name resolution (*Edit -> Preferences -> Name Resolution -> Resolve Network (IP) addresses -> [deselect]*), then I think you should be able to use the "*`matches`*" operator to filter out the packets you're not concerned with, e.g.:

```
!(ip.host ~ "\.6[01]$")
```

Refer to the [Wireshark man page](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html), [Wireshark DisplayFilters](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DisplayFilters) wiki page, or [Wireshark User Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) for more information, as well as the [Perl Documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for help with Perl-compatible regular expressions.